# Custom object detection using Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, mscoco

I want to detect helmet and person not wearing helmet.. I use ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017 model with 1000 helmet images and 1000 without helmet.

1) Is that ok to use ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017 model for training? If not then what model I can use? (because COCO have only 90 classes and helmet not in that list)

can somebody help me to clear my doubt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer following links  to achieve this

https://pythonprogramming.net/training-custom-objects-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/

https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-toy-detector-with-tensorflow-object-detection-api-63c0fdf2ac95

https://medium.com/@dana.yu/training-a-custom-object-detection-model-41093ddc5797

Comment: Thanks for your help